# Jquery child table ID

Tags: jquery

Trying to grab the table ID from table id="1"
 in below html / script
when click on Account or Bill link I would like to grab the table ID so I could pass that table ID to another function to grab AJAX data. table ID is crated dyno. this is test data

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {                  
                $('.toggler').click(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $(this).parent().find('.content').slideToggle();
                    var a = $(this).next("div").find(".content").children().attr("id");
                    alert(a);

                }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id="MainTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="toggler-wrap">
                            <a href="#" class="toggler">Account </a>
                            <a href="#" class="toggler">Bill</a>
                            <div class="content">   
                                <table id="1">
                                    <tr><td>Content will come here</td></tr>                                    
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id="MainTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="toggler-wrap">
                            <a href="#" class="toggler">Account</a>
                            <a href="#" class="toggler">Bill</a>
                            <div class="content">   
                                <table id="2">
                                    <tr><td>Content will come here</td></tr>                                    
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot have a number as an ID, call it id="tab1" or something like that.

Comment: Maybe you "cannot", but even so an expression like `$("#1").append('<tr><td>bla bla</td></tr>');` still works :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.toggler').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).parent().find('.content').slideToggle();
   var a = $(this).parent().find('table').attr("id");
   alert(a);
});
```

Comment: Correct, here is [live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/c8S9n/) to help visualize this.

Answer (score 1):

you can get it like this

```
$('.content').find('table').attr('id');
```

**Updated Code:**

```
 $('.toggler').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().find('.content').slideToggle();
      var a = $(this).parent().find(".content").find('table').attr('id');
      alert(a);
 });
```

[Updated Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RpakG/60/)

Comment: What would be the Jquey liner to get the a link Content so I know which link is clicked as well –

Comment: you can use $(this) in your js function to get on which link you have clicked or if you want link text you can use $(this).text();

Comment: $('.toggler').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault(); 
var linkContent =  $(this).text();
$(this).parent().find('.content').slideToggle();
var contentTableId = $(this).parent().find('table').attr("id"); 
SetTranslateData(contentTableId); 
});

Comment: I have above toggler and when view link is clicked slideToggle() works fine and I call setTranslateData function. do some work there. When i click view link again to close the toggle, But i would like to stop calling function again.. how can i complish this behaviour..thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would add an attribute to each link that contains the Id that you want to search for then use that to find the specific table you are looking for.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {                  
                $('.toggler').click(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var targetId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                    //Call ajax with the target Id

                    var content = $('table[id="' + targetId + '"] td').text();
                    alert(content);

                    $(this).parent().find('.content').slideToggle();
                }); 
            });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id="MainTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="toggler-wrap">
                            <a href="#" class="toggler" data-id="1">Account </a>
                            <a href="#" class="toggler" data-id="1">Bill</a>
                            <div class="content">   
                                <table id="1">
                                    <tr><td>Content for id 1</td></tr>                                    
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id="MainTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="toggler-wrap">
                            <a href="#" class="toggler" data-id="2">Account</a>
                            <a href="#" class="toggler" data-id="2">Bill</a>
                            <div class="content">   
                                <table id="2">
                                    <tr><td>Content for id 2</td></tr>                                    
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What would be the Jquey liner to get the a link Content so I know which link is clicked as well